# defining abilities (CanCan) with has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I am a beginner in rails and have been trawling through many suggested answers to this problem. I can't seem to translate the answers, I've seen to my situation. I'm hoping someone would be kind enough to shed some light on it.
The 2 models, I am concerned with are User and Project. Each User can create a project, but each user can also manage a project. To allow for this, I have created a has_many :through relationship between **User** and **Project**, using a managing model to connect the two models.

user.rb

```
 has_many :managings, foreign_key: "manager_id", dependent: :destroy
 has_many :managed_projects, through: :managings
```

managing.rb

```
belongs_to :manager, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :managed_project, class_name: "Project"
```

project.rb

```
has_one :reverse_managing, foreign_key: "managed_project_id",
                                class_name:  "Managing",
                                dependent:   :destroy
has_one :manager, through: :reverse_managing, source: :manager
```

So, I have a role called 'Beginner'. Beginners can only read projects, with the exception of those who choose to be managers of a project. Managers should also be allowed to edit and update a project, which they are managing.

Below is my attempt at this in ability.rb

```
 user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
  if user.role? :Admin
    can :manage, :all
  elsif user.role? :Author
    can :read, :all
    can [:create], [Project]
    can [:edit, :update], Project, :user_id => user.id
  elsif user.role? :Beginner
   can :read, :all

   can [:edit, :update], Project, :manager_id => user.id
  end
```

The last line doesn't appear to be working, as I am not seeing an edit link when I look at the project view of a beginner who is managing that project.

Here is the code that I use in the view:

```
<% if can? :update, project  %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project) %>
<% end %>
```

and this is what appears in projects_controller

```
def edit
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  authorize! :edit, @project
end
```

I will sleep a happy man if someone can help me on this

UPDATE

here is the role? method in User.rb

```
def role?(role)
  return !!self.roles.find_by_name(role.to_s.camelize)
end
```

UPDATE

I had the wrong role_id assigned to the user. After correcting this, I got an error message, when I tried to open the project view containing the edit link.

```
undefined method `manager_id' for #<Project:0xb387f0b0>
```

Comment: Are you sure the role? method is doing what it's supposed to? `:Beginner` looks... awkward

Comment: Let me get some right, you have defined inside your `elsif` block that a `:Beginner` can 1) edit 2) update a project providing that the `manager_id => user.id` is provided. Something does not seem right.

Comment: The beginner has the option to become a manager of the project. In this case they are allowed to manage that particular project. When I say manage, I mean they can manage the operation of the project in the real world. This has nothing to do with managing the resource. So the logic should be 'allow the beginner to edit or update the project, as long they have assigned themselves as manager of the project'. The beginner is volunteering to manage the project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
can [:edit, :update], Project, :manager_id => user.id
```

cancan ability conditions must only use database columns (as per the [cancan wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities)). Here cancan  expects manager_id to be a column in the Project model, which is actually is not the case. Your models look somewhat like this:

User [id, ...]
Project [id, ...]
Managings [manager_id, managed_project_id, ...]

manager_id is a field in Managings, and not in Project.

The fix is to use block conditions as described in another [wiki page](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks). I've not tested it, but I think the following will work -

```
can [:edit, :update], Project do |p|
 p.manager == user
end
```

Comment: @abhishek, but what if project has many managers? `p.managers.map(&:id).include? user.id`